# refrescar una region luego de seleccionar un valor desde una lista de valores

Tags: apex

Como hago para que después de haber seleccionado un valor en una lista de valores se refresque solo la región donde se encuentra la lista de valores y no toda la pagina, actualmente si selecciono un valor inmediatamente se actualiza la región pero se dirige al inicio de la pagina en uso.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado/investigado?

Answer (score 1):

Use acciones dinámicas para refrescar solamente el reporte / gráfico que necesita.
Como ejemplo,

1. Navegue a la sección de Acciones Dinámicas y crea una nueva. Alli puede definir cual es el evento que dispara las acciones
2. Defina las acciones que necesita que se ejecuten
3. Defina la región, elemento u otro, involucrado en la acción

[image: Navegue a la sección de Acciones Dinámicas y crea una nueva. Alli puede definir cual es el evento que dispara las acciones]
[image: Defina las acciones que necesita que se ejecuten]
[image: Defina la región, elemento u otro, involucrado en la acción]

Puedes leer más en la documentación de APEX:
[Dynamic Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmdb/managing-dynamic-actions.html#GUID-7E564715-E963-44AA-B620-5FFB5EFA62EE)